# fread returning wrong data

Tags: matlab, fopen, fread

I am using `fread` to read file located in my C disk ,the content of files are:

```
ssa.txt:  0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

ssb.txt:  0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 1
```

But fread is reading

Columns 1 through 25

```
48    48    48    48    48    49    49    49    49    48    48    48    48    48    48    48    49    49    49    49    49    48    48    48    48
```

Columns 26 through 31

```
48    48    48    48    48    48
```

My code:

```
n = 31;
fid =fopen('ssa.txt');
s1 = fread(fid,[1,n]);
fclose(fid);

fid2 =fopen('ssb.txt');
s2 = fread(fid2,[1,n]);
fclose(fid2);
```

Can someone explain me what is wrong?

Comment: 48 and 49 sound like the ascii representation of 0 and 1, as characters. So `'0'` and `'1'`. As [the docs](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fread.html) say, `fread` reads *binary* files, but you have a text file. Use something like [`textscan`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/textscan.html) (or `fgetl` plus `num2str2`, etc.) instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exactly why `fread` does that I'm not sure, I reckon it has something to do with that `fread` reads binaries and those numbers are the ASCII representation of `0`and `1`. The work around I'd suggest is using [`dlmread`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dlmread.html) for numbers only:

```
dlmread('SSA.txt')
ans =
  Columns 1 through 16
     0     0     0     0     0     1     1     1     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
  Columns 17 through 31
     1     1     1     1     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
```

Comment: The real question is why the spaces between the numbers are not being read as characters.

Comment: @AndrasDeak if you use *exactly* that file, you'll get the OP's series interleaved with `32`, the ASCII value for white space. I guess their files don't actually contain white space.